# Ruby: Console-based menu

Tags: ruby, user-interface

I have an array of Names and URLs and would like to present the user with a list of the names in form of an up-/down-scrollable menu. Basically what `dialog` allows within the shell.

I have looked into `ncurses-ruby`, `rdialog` and `HighLine` but they all seem to be either abandoned as a project or throw errors even from their examples (if at all existent).

Could someone kindly point me to either a nice, usable gem that does TUI menus *or* a simple (I'll be new to this then...) introduction on how to to this in Rails (ie. presentation of available data (=what I have in my array)) and how to handle the user's choice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think all of your proposals are valid, then there come more (n)curses wrappers, and more evolved framworks like [rutui](https://github.com/b1nary/rutui), [rbcurse](https://github.com/rkumar/rbcurse-core) (unfortunately not active), [vedeu](https://github.com/gavinlaking/vedeu) and probably some others.

However, my take for now would be **[hirb](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) or [highline](https://github.com/JEG2/highline)** which are both stable and actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Green shoes is a nice gem for this kind of work, it has menu's, selects, editboxes, filedialogs, checkboxes etc while being simple and having no dependencies other than Ruby itself.

There is a small but very active community with a mailing list to ask for help.
See http://vgoff.posterous.com/green-shoes for more info.
Installation is with `gem install green_shoes`

Here a small example

```
Shoes.app title: 'Selecteer vakantie', height: 600 do
  background lightgreen..lightskyblue, :angle => 30
  @list = ["choice1","choice2"]
  @result = []
  stack do
    para "Make your choice.", font: "sans", size: 10
    flow do
      button "Ok" do
        selected = @list.map{|c, n| n if c.checked?}.compact
        @result[0].text = "you selected #{selected}"
      end
      button("End") {exit}
    end
    @list.map! do |name|
      flow { @c = check; para name, width: 500, font: "sans", size: 10 }
      [@c, name]
    end
    @result << para('', :stroke => forestgreen)
  end
end
```

Comment: I might be mistaken (currently I am still trying to build Green Shoes under OS X, theres quite q few dependencies to natively build it :) but this appears to be a GUI gem. I was looking for a Text based User Interface, aka. something ncurses/dialog-like. But a nice thing to look into anyways!

Comment: ah, in windows with the installer it is all included, most of the time it is the opposite and we have more work to get it to work