# Command Line Radio Buttons/Options in Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-interface

How do we make a command line options like this:
[image]

I would image the code would look like this

```
options = Hash.new()
options['Monolithic'] = 'Monolithic application'
options['Microservice'] = 'Microservice application'
options['Gateway'] = 'Microservice gateway'
puts 'Which *type* of application would you like to create?'
options.each do |key, option|
  puts option
end
# interface here
```

Answer (score 0):

A menu in a console windows can be done with several gems, the best known are [curses](https://github.com/ruby/curses), [tty-prompt](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-prompt) and derivates and [Highlight](https://rubygems.org/gems/highlight/versions/2.0.0)

If you want a simple graphical menu see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955395/ruby-console-based-menu).

See [here](https://gist.github.com/phoet/6988038) for an example of what curses can do.
[Here](https://totalrecall.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/rubycurses-some-code-samples/) are more examples.

Result will depend on OS and console being used.

Comment: Is it possible to not open it in a new window?

Comment: window, like graphical ? you mean the Shoes example, yes it does

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [tty-prompt](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-prompt) gem to help build interactive menus. Implementation of the example would look like:

```
require "tty-prompt"

prompt = TTY::Prompt.new
type = prompt.decorate("*type*", :yellow)
prompt.select("Which #{type} of application would you like to create?") do |menu|
  menu.choice "Monolithic application", "Monolithic"
  menu.choice "Microservice application", "Microservice"
  menu.choice "Microservice gateway", "Gateway"
end
```

The above will render the following select menu in the console:

[image]

This gem is tested to work on a variety of operating systems and there are many types of prompts available.